# OpenGL: render time limit on linux

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, shader, gpu

I'm implementing some computation algorithm via OpenGL and Qt. All computations are executed in fragment shader.

Sometimes when i trying to execute some hard computations (that takes more than 5 seconds on GPU) OpenGL breaks computation before it ends. I suppose this is system like [TDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570087(v=vs.85).aspx) from Windows.

I think that i should split input data by several parts but i need to know how long computation allowed.

How i can obtain render time limit on linux (it will be cool if there is crossplatform solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. After a lot of scouring through the documentation of both X and Wayland, I could not find *anything* mentioning GPU watchdog timer settings, so I believe this is driver-specific and likely inaccessible to the user (that or I am terrible at searching).

It is however possible to disable this watchdog under X **on NVIDIA hardware** by adding a line to your `xorg.conf`, which is then passed on to the graphics driver.

> **Option "Interactive" "boolean"**
>
> This option controls the behavior of the driver's watchdog, which attempts to detect and terminate GPU programs that get stuck, in order to ensure that the GPU remains available for other processes. GPU compute applications, however, often have long-running GPU programs, and killing them would be undesirable. If you are using GPU compute applications and they are getting prematurely terminated, try turning this option off.

Note that even the NVIDIA docs don't mention a numeric quantity for the timeout.

Comment: Does this timer still apply for compute shaders?

Comment: I was wondering because some GPU can run both compute and graphics at the same time, so the driver can still update the desktop even if a very long compute task is running (in theory). But yeah from a driver point of view it's probably safer to have time limit for everything anyways.